# Unparseable date Exception

Tags: android, exception, date

Well, i'm trying to catch date from rss, and i get this execption in logcat:

```
E/AndroidNews(  870): Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Su
n, 02 Oct 2011 14:00:00 +0100"
E/AndroidNews(  870):   at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
E/AndroidNews(  870):   at com.warriorpoint.androidxmlsimple.Message.setDate(Mes
sage.java:57)
```

My **formatter** is

> static SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = 
>           new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");´

My method setDate();

```
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date=null;

    // pad the date if necessary
    while (!date.endsWith("00")){
        date += "0";
    }
    try {
        this.date = FORMATTER.parse(date.trim());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is clearly seen that the input is not in the expected date format. So, a ParseException is normal, isn't it?

Comment: A bit off topic, but NEVER put SimpleDateFormat into static variable. You'll just end up using the same SimpleDateFormat instance from multiple threads and produce wrong dates and times since it is not thread safe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the wrong format, for "Sun, 02 Oct 2011 14:00:00 +0100" try this instead:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US)
```

This also forces the locale to (American) English, so the day and month names aren't affected by the device's locale, e.g. expecting "Dom" for "Sun" and "Oct" for "Out" in a Portuguese locale (I peeked at your profile).

The format you have in your question would only be able to parse dates like "2011-10-02 14:00".

Also, don't pad the date, let your formatter do the parsing.

---

If you want to output/display a `java.util.Date` in a certain way, just create a new `SimpleDateFormat` (let's call it `displayFmt`) with the desired formatting string and call `format()` on it:

```
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy H").format(date);
```

This will give you something like "02 10 2011 17" for today, formatted in the user's/device's preferred locale.

Please note that in your comment, you said `dd mm yyyy h` (lower case `m` and `h`) which would give you "dayOfMonth *minutes* year hours12" -- I think that's not what you want, so I changed it to an upper case `M` and upper case `H` to give you "dayOfMonth *month* year *hours24*".

Comment: I changed the format and works in emulator, but in my real phone the exception is happening, and i saw the logcat and him refers to this line :

`this.date = FORMATTER.parse(date.trim());`

Comment: Did you update the app on your phone? Does `logcat` on your phone contain the same stacktrace and message as the one in your question? (You can check your phone's `logcat` when it's plugged in just like an emulator) -- please update your question with the new info, comments are too small for this.

Comment: Yes, i updated my app.

Here is the log errors of my phone's logcat -> [link](http://pastebin.com/mML1q5k7).

The curious thing is that it works perfectly in the emulator and not on my phone.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your device runs with a different locale than the emulator -- try `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);` to force (American) English names for days and months.

Comment: Now works perfectly! Really thanks Philipp Reichart!

Now i have a question, it's possible to show only the day month year and the hour? Like dd mm yyyy h

Thanks again!

Comment: Check out my answer, I updated it with a snippet on date formatting.

Comment: Once again, works perfectly! I don't want to be annoying, but i have another problem, because the news that i "catch" from rss have "15h" but in my list appear with "14h". Any idea? Or I'd better create another topic?
Thanks

Comment: Last one before I'm off to a party tonight: `SimpleDateFormat` automatically applies the "+0100" timezone part and formats the displayed date into your local time zone.